# How can I set a specific page transition from Page1.html into Page2.html?

Tags: javascript, html, css, transition

Using http://tympanus.net/Development/PageTransitions/

Take a look at that website, and the transition i'm trying to work with is 'rotate > room >'

Here's the [github repo](https://github.com/codrops/PageTransitions) of where I'm at, but I'm very lost and this is getting extremely difficult to incorporate.  What I want to achieve is for example:

Homepage.html > room to left > leftpage.html

leftpage.html (ONLY HAS 1 OPTION) > room to right > homepage.html

Answer (score 2):

Note that the URL on the site you link to never changes for the different "pages."  All the content is on a single page.  It's not possible to control the transition the browser displays between two completely different HTML pages.  If you can re-implement your site as a single-page site, you'll be able to use CSS transitions to switch between different content divs.

Comment: Hi Adv12,

I understand that, and I was planning on re-implementing the site as a single-page site...but I can figure out the section id's for each different page later on. The real question and problem is specifying a  specific and unique transition for each page.

For example, when I'm on "section_Home" and click the menu to go to the "section_Music" page, I need that transition to be unique, let's say transition(LeftToRight). Now that I'm on "section_Music", I need "transition(RightToLeft) to activate.

I'm sure you understand what I'm saying, but check out the actual code  from the demo...

Comment: (continued) but if you look at the code, it gives you options to add different pages. Originally they are various different colored pages, which I replaced with iframe embed's of html sites to test. These pages are defined by 
'<div class="pt-page pt-page-1">ContentOnPage</div>'

However, my problem is specifying '<li data-animation="54"><a href="#">Room to left--this is the menu link</a></li>' to go to dedicated page. @adv12